# JavaScript for finding the latitude and longitude of number of places

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

I have never used JavaScript. In my application I am using SQL Server database 2005 which contains almost 2200 addresses of a particular city. I have to find the latitude and longitude of all these locations. For that I want to use JavaScript. Can someone guide me how to use JavaScript for finding latitude and longitude of multiple addresses?

Comment: Why does it need to be JavaScript? First build your server application and show it to us, then we might lead you to how to enhance it with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "new york";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: i tried this.it is working for a single address.but wen i use it for n number of addresses it is not working.

Comment: that's what i am saying, show me how you are putting the code in loop?

Comment: Line 21 the address:address should be address:address[i]; no need for pastie you are iterating it wrong